# ImportError in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, dependencies, jupyter-notebook, package

I am trying import a module in Jupyter and it is not working:

```
import alyn
```

---

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8e9535ea4303> in <module>()
----> 1 import alyn

~\Anaconda3\envs\tracx\lib\site-packages\alyn\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 """ Import required modules"""
----> 2 from deskew import *
      3 from skew_detect import *

ImportError: No module named 'deskew'
```

I don't quite understand why, since the package in question has a correct **init**.py file:

[image]

whose contents are:

```
""" Import required modules"""
from deskew import *
from skew_detect import *
```

What am I missing?

P.S.
This is all taking place on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I've figured it out!

Turns out that the package I was trying to import is written in Python 2 and its init file is using the **relative import** mechanism. However, I am working in Python 3 and relative import is no longer supported in it. The init file can be made to work in Python 3 by adding a . in both lines, like this:

```
""" Import required modules"""
from .deskew import *
from .skew_detect import *
```

I *think* this should be backward compatible with Python 2.